# Inheriting the height of another td by index in an each()

Tags: jquery, inheritance, indexing, html-table

I'm trying to make its parallel td inherit the height of another td. In my example I'm trying to make the td Volvo inherit the Tiger td but for some reason it will only run for the first td it finds and not the rest.

I would very much appreciate your help!

```js
        $("tr").each(function(index, elem) {
            var animals = $(this).find(".animals");
            var cars = $(this).find(".cars");
            $(cars).eq(animals.index()).height(animals.height())
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Striped Rows</h2>
        <p>The .table-striped class adds zebra-stripes to a table:</p>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Animals</th>
                    <th>Cars</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Doe</td>
                    <td>john@example.com</td>
                    <td>Cow</td>
                    <td>Mouse</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mary</td>
                    <td>Moe</td>
                    <td>mary@example.com</td>
                    <td>Cat</td>
                    <td>Dog</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>July</td>
                    <td>Dooley</td>
                    <td>july@example.com</td>
                    <td>
                        <p class="animals" style="height:80px;">Fish</p>
                        <p class="animals">Bird</p>
                        <p class="animals" style="height:60px;">Tiger</p>
                        <p class="animals">Rhino</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p class="cars">Mazda</p>
                        <p class="cars">Honda</p>
                        <p class="cars">Volvo</p>
                        <p class="cars">Opel</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you have 4 `<p>` tags with `animals` class and similar tags with `cars` class. So exactly what is the issue? Does the issue with `<td>` height or height of `<p>` present within these columns?

Comment: the `td` Mazda is inheriting the height of the `td` fish, which is right. But the `td` Volvo is not inheriting the height of `td` Tiger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab `<p>` tag's index and height and need to apply it to corresponding `<p>` tag present in last column as follows:

```js
$("tr").each(function(index, elem) {
  var animals = $(this).find(".animals");
  var trObj = $(this);
  var cars = $(trObj).find(".cars");
  $(animals).each(function(index1, elem1) {
    
    $(cars).eq($(this).index()).height($(this).height())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Striped Rows</h2>
    <p>The .table-striped class adds zebra-stripes to a table:</p>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Animals</th>
          <th>Cars</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>john@example.com</td>
          <td>Cow</td>
          <td>Mouse</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mary</td>
          <td>Moe</td>
          <td>mary@example.com</td>
          <td>Cat</td>
          <td>Dog</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
          <td>
            <p class="animals" style="height:80px;">Fish</p>
            <p class="animals">Bird</p>
            <p class="animals" style="height:60px;">Tiger</p>
            <p class="animals">Rhino</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="cars">Mazda</p>
            <p class="cars">Honda</p>
            <p class="cars">Volvo</p>
            <p class="cars">Opel</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```